# How to turn node.js app into android app?

Tags: javascript, android, node.js

i decided to delve into web dev a few months ago and after feeling somewhat comfortable with the front-end basics (html/css/js) i began exploring node for some back-end knowledge and came up with a project for exercising.

There's a webpage displaying in detail the current weather conditions of the area i live in, so i would like to create an app for my android phone with the content of the page since the page is pretty basic (just some html tables) and non-responsive so i must zoom and side-scroll on my phone to see the content, plus i have to open a browser and navigate there.

So i have managed to scrape what i want and serve it locally on my pc (with express). And this i where i am not sure how to proceed. What is the simplest and/or more efficient way to turn this into an android app?

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion there is no totally simple way to just convert this into a native android app.
Since you are using javascript you might want to look into React Native to develop the app.

Answer (score 0):

### There are 2 options for you.

#### 1. Use webview in Android and iOS

So once user open your app it will load your website but it's require internet connection. And the first activity will be loaded fully once site has been loaded.

#### 2. Use Ionic/cordova

Cordova is my recommended method because user never gonna feel that the site is built with HTML CSS.
To do that you need use static site and that site will consume api from your server. You can use Vue/React/Angular for speedup the development.